# INSERT into table without specifying Column names and changing the values in a known column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a T1 table and the data of this month are missing, so i want to duplicate the datas of january in this table T1 with changing the values of the column "month" to february.

I only know the name of the month column.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I am using oracle

Comment: Is the month column you refers to of type Date or does it only contain the month and what type is it then?

Comment: it contains the year and the month like that '201901' , it's a char column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you *can't* write something like

```
INSERT INTO someTable(column1,*)
SELECT value, * FROM someTable WHERE ...
```

where you mix a single column name with '*'

I think this needs to be done in separate steps if possible, first create a temp table and fill it with data for the wanted  month

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE a
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
AS
select * from someTable where monthColumn = '201901';
```

Then update the month column in the temp table

```
UPDATE a SET monthColumn  = '201902';
```

Then "copy" the data back to the original table

```
INSERT INTO  someTable 
SELECT * FROM a;
```

Comment: Thank youuu, a temporary table .. that must work, i will try this... thank you :D

Comment: Oops... I should have read the sentence before first...

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Didnt read clearly, sry. I deleted my comment. It's the small things that matter :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
insert into tablename
select col1, col2, 'February', col4
from tablename
where month = 'January' and year = 2019
```

I.e. you select the January rows, but put February in the month column.

Comment: I dont know the names of my columns...

Comment: Simply `select * from t1`  and you'll see.

Comment: yeah i kwnow, but in my case, when i select all the column, there are longs columns  and in the selection it shows me just the 9 first charachter of the columns

Answer (score 0):

That's a little bit awkward requirement, but - here's one option: it selects column names from `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` and composes the `INSERT` statement based on it.

Test case:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> create table t1 (id number, c_date date, amount number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into t1
  2    select 1, date '2019-01-12', 100 from dual union all     --> to be copied
  3    select 2, date '2019-01-08', 200 from dual union all     --> to be copied
  4    select 3, date '2018-12-25', 300 from dual;

3 rows created.

SQL> select * from t1 order by id;

        ID C_DATE         AMOUNT
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 12.01.2019        100
         2 08.01.2019        200
         3 25.12.2018        300
```

Code:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_date_column varchar2(30) := 'C_DATE';
  3    l_coll        varchar2(200);
  4    l_str varchar2(200);
  5  begin
  6    select listagg(column_name, ', ') within group (order by column_id)
  7      into l_coll
  8      from user_tab_columns
  9      where table_name = 'T1';
 10
 11    l_coll := replace(l_coll, 'C_DATE', 'add_months(C_DATE, 1)');
 12
 13    l_str := 'insert into t1 select ' || l_coll || ' from t1 ' ||
 14             'where trunc(c_date, ''mm'') = date ''2019-01-01''';
 15    execute immediate(l_str);
 16  end;
 17  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * From t1 order by id;

        ID C_DATE         AMOUNT
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 12.01.2019        100
         1 12.02.2019        100
         2 08.01.2019        200
         2 08.02.2019        200
         3 25.12.2018        300

SQL>
```